# How do I force git to use a different port when ssh'ing to a remote?

Tags: git, repository, remote-access

I want to change the port of my remote branch.  I executed this command

```
localhost:myproject satishp$ git remote add production rails@my-project.com:7822:/home/rails/myproject
```

However, when I try and push to that branch, I'm getting complaints about port 22 not being open.  This is true. It is not open but that's why I tried to change the port in the statement above.

```
localhost:myproject satishp$ git push production master
ssh: connect to host my-project.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How do I properly change the port of my remote?  This is with Git v 2.62 on Mac if taht matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port is allowed in `ssh://` URLs but not in `scp`. To fix:

```
git remote set-url production ssh://rails@my-project.com:7822/home/rails/myproject
```